# Cut Columns and Append to Same File

Tags: awk, append, pipe, cut

I'm working with a tab separated file on MacOS.  The file contains 15 columns and thousands of rows.  I want to cut columns 1, 2, and 3 and then append them with columns 11, 12, and 13.  I was hoping to do this in a pipe so that no extra files need to be created.  The only post I found used a command `sponge` but I evidently don't have that on MacOS, or it isn't in my BASH.

The input tsv file is actually being generated within the same line of code,

`arbitrary command to generate input.tsv | cut -f1-3,11-13 | <Step to cut -f4-6 and append -f1-3> | sort > out.file`

**Input tsv**

```
chr1    21018   21101   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   chr1    20752   21209
chr10   74645   74836   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   chr10   74638   74898
chr10   75267   75545   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   chr10   75280   75917
chr4    212478  212556  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   chr4    212491  213285
```

**Desired Output tsv**

```
chr1    21018   21101
chr1    20752   21209
chr10   74638   74898
chr10   74645   74836
chr10   75280   75917
chr4    212478  212556
chr4    212491  213285
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

### code

```
perl -pe 's/chr[0-9]+/\n$&/g' file | awk '/./{print $1, $2, $3}'
```

### Output

```
chr1 21018 21101
chr1 20752 21209
chr10 74645 74836
chr10 74638 74898
chr10 75267 75545
chr10 75280 75917
chr4 212478 212556
chr4 212491 213285
```

Comment: Hi Gilles.  Is there a way to pipe this with paste? This isn't quite right, but maybe you would see how to adjust the paste command below?  <br/> `arbitrary command to generate input.tsv | cut -f1-3,11-13 | paste <(cut -f1-3 test.bed) <(cut -f4-6 test.bed | sort > out.file`

Answer (score 0):

here is short `awk` solution:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, "\n" $1, $12, $13;}' input.tsv
```

#### output:

```
chr1 21018 21101 
chr1 20752 21209
chr10 74645 74836 
chr10 74638 74898
chr10 75267 75545 
chr10 75280 75917
chr4 212478 212556 
chr4 212491 213285
```

#### Explanation

```
{ # for each input line
    print $1, $2, $3; # print 1st field, append 2nd and 3rd fields. Terminate with new line
    print $1, $12, $13; #print 1st field, append 12th and 13th field. Terminate with new line
}
```